# What is the correct way to disable SSH password authentication

Tags: server, ssh, password, authentication

I have seen two recommendations for disabling password authentication after having transferred your public SSH key to an Ubuntu server. Each involves a different modification of the `sshd_config` file.

1. This [Digital Ocean](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-ssh-keys--2) article recommends `PermitRootLogin without-password`
2. [This tutorial](https://www.rosehosting.com/blog/how-to-set-up-ssh-keys-on-ubuntu-16-04/) recommends `PasswordAuthentication no`

What is the difference between the two?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`PermitRootLogin without-password` is a bit of a misnomer (which is why in recent versions of OpenSSH it is deprecated in favour of `PermitRootLogin prohibit-password`). What it does is allow root to login, but only through methods other than password authentication; for example key-based authentication is allowed. It has no effect on users other than root.

`PasswordAuthentication no` prohibits password authentication for all users. Note that, by using a `Match` block, it is possible to prohibit password authentication for only some users, or to allow it for some users when it is globally prohibited:

```
# Prohibit password authentication only for user foo
Match User foo
    PasswordAuthentication no
```

---

```
# Prohibit password authentication for all users other than foo
PasswordAuthentication no
Match User foo
    PasswordAuthentication yes
```

`Match` blocks can also match other things, for example by using hostname matching you can allow password authentication from machines on the local network only. See `man sshd_config` for details.