# Can I force a specific user to login by SSH cert only while all other accounts can still SSH by password?

Tags: ssh, login, password, certificates

Ubuntu wizards,

I'm trying to set a user to only be able to login via cert through SSH but allow all other users to login via password through SSH. For some reason, I'm not getting how to set this config to affect only this single specific user and not the whole system. Can anyone run down how (if it's possible) this can be done?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Related answer: [What is the correct way to disable SSH password authentication](https://askubuntu.com/a/1161230/178692)

Answer (score 5):

I have not tested this myself (as I enforce key auth for everything and only have a very limited use of password auth), but setting `PasswordAuthentication yes` earlier in the `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` file, and then this added to the end of that same file might solve this for the one user:

```
Match User username
    PasswordAuthentication no
```

Change `username` to the matching user's name.

Then restart your SSH service.  `sudo systemctl restart ssh.service`

Comment: It worked! Thank you so much! I couldn't find the "Match User" setting in anything for a week haha. This was all for an Ansible playbook for creating a user and setting it to only be able to login via cert:  

   - name: Set sshd_config to PasswordAuthentication no
      become: yes
      blockinfile:
        path: /etc/ssh/sshd_config
        marker: "# {mark} ANSIBLE MANAGED BLOCK - {{username}}"
        block: |
           Match User "{{ username}}"
              PasswordAuthentication no

Comment: @ZackPerry glad to hear it helped!  Don't forget to hit the checkmark on the answer to mark it as the accepted answer :)